Is there a way to print a bank check from a template where the user only puts the amount and the name?
I've been trying in Excel to create a template for printing a bank check. I've set the dimensions and everything, but always has print issues as it's not perfectly aligned, so I've thought in some other way. like coding an entire program in Python (GUI) that only needs the information (amount, location, date, name), it did create a PDF file. but when I print it, it doesn't align well, like for example, the amount isn't exactly put in the box of the check, and the same goes for the amount in letters.
I really need help with this. I'm so lost in this. I've tried everything.
This is the code of the program I did:
import tkinter as tk
from fpdf import FPDF
import num2words

def generate_cheque():
    amount = amount_entry.get().replace(" ", "")
    amount_parts = amount.split(".")
    amount_in_letters = num2words.num2words(int(amount_parts[0]), lang='fr').replace("virgule", "comma").replace("zero", "")
    amount_in_letters += " dinars algeriens"
    if int(amount_parts[1]) > 0:
        amount_in_letters += " et " + num2words.num2words(int(amount_parts[1]), lang='fr').replace("virgule", "comma").replace("zero", "") + " centimes"
    location = location_entry.get()
    date = date_entry.get()
    company_name = company_name_entry.get()
    

    # Convert dimensions from inches to points
    width_in_inches = 8.5
    height_in_inches = 3.5
    width_in_points = width_in_inches * 72
    height_in_points = height_in_inches * 72

    pdf = FPDF(unit="pt", format=(width_in_points, height_in_points))
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)

    # Add date
    pdf.set_xy(480, 150)
    pdf.cell(0, 10, txt=date, align="R")


    # Add amount in numbers
    pdf.set_xy(450, 50)
    pdf.cell(0, 10, txt=amount, align="R")

    # add location
    pdf.set_xy(400,150)
    pdf.cell(0,10, txt=location, align="L")

    # Add amount in letters
    pdf.set_xy(110,70)
    pdf.multi_cell(0, 10, txt=amount_in_letters, align="L")

    # Add company name
    pdf.set_xy(50, 120)
    pdf.cell(0, 10, txt=company_name, align="L")

    # Save the PDF
    pdf.output("cheque.pdf", "F")

    result_label.config(text="Cheque generated successfully!")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Cheque Generator")

amount_label = tk.Label(root, text="Amount (000 000 000.00):")
amount_label.pack()
amount_entry = tk.Entry(root)
amount_entry.pack()


location_label = tk.Label(root, text="Location:")
location_label.pack()
location_entry = tk.Entry(root)
location_entry.pack()

date_label = tk.Label(root, text="Date (DD.MM.YYYY):")
date_label.pack()
date_entry = tk.Entry(root)
date_entry.pack()

company_name_label = tk.Label(root, text="Company Name:")
company_name_label.pack()
company_name_entry = tk.Entry(root)
company_name_entry.pack()

generate_button = tk.Button(root, text="Generate Cheque", command=generate_cheque)
generate_button.pack()

result_label = tk.Label(root, text="")
result_label.pack()

root.mainloop()

Is there a way to like creates the perfectly aligned PDF check file?

thank you but what i want is not an actual check i just want when i print the info (the amount, date...) will be printed on its respective place like the amount for example i want when i print it it's prints on that box, so it's not a matter of design but matter of printing
